FFmpeg: ffv1 -context parameter
What forces ffv1 to encode in intra-frame mode -context 0 or -g 1 or both?
It says here (in Compression details) that to force intra-frame encoding I should use -context 0 (as far as I understand).
But here it says nothing about -context (only mentions it in copying audio "as-is") but says about -g 1 and -slicecrc 1 for archival use


What forces ffv1 to encode in intra-frame mode

it's:
-context 0

example:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v ffv1 -context 0 -level 3 output.mkv


-i input.mp4 specifies the input file
-c:v ffv1 sets the video codec to FFV1
-context 0 determines how much information from other frames is used for prediction. setting it to 0 means no inter-frame prediction is used, effectively forcing intra-frame encoding
-level 3 sets the FFV1 level (optional, but recommended for better compatibility)
output.mkv specifies the output file


bonus:

-g 1
while this parameter sets the GOP (Group of Pictures) size to 1, which would typically force keyframes for every frame in many codecs, it's not actually necessary for FFV1 when -context 0 is used. FFV1 doesn't use traditional GOP structures like some other codecs do

-slicecrc 1 this option adds error detection capabilities, which is good for archival purposes, but doesn't affect the intra-frame encoding directly



What does -context then do? I know about this question
where gyan answered but since I'm not educated enough i can't understand..... tysm
